# Changing connection string from dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a basic MVC app to do CRUD operations on database tables. I'm using Entity Framework Database First, so I was able to just scaffold out controllers and views very quickly.

We have a dev, qa, and prod database. The schema should be identical with only the data in each being different.

I want to create a dropdown that will let me change the connection string from the app. I'm not sure the best way to do this. It currently works just fine using the dev connection string, but if I manually change the database to qa from web.config, whenever I try to create or update an existing record from the app, I get this error:

**"The UPDATE permission was denied on the object"**

I don't get this error using the dev database.

Comment: Changing the connection string using a drop down won't solve this problem. You'll need to check/update the permissions in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your database permissions.

Use the following link and go through the security/permissions and you will be able to solved the problem.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/23/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-security-a-primer/

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your user has the same permissions on qa/prod as it does in dev.